# SQL syntax highlighting is not applied on PHP question

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Suddenly the editor stopped highlighting the keywords in `SQL`. For example `SELECT`, `FROM`, `INNER JOIN`, etc. should be highlighted in blue, but it’s not happening. This is my query and here is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482173/order-by-all-columns):

```
SELECT student.firstname,
       candidates.partylist,
       candidates.position
FROM   student
       INNER JOIN candidates
               ON student.student_id = candidates.student_id
ORDER  BY partylist,
          CASE position
            WHEN 'President' THEN 1
            WHEN 'VicePresident' THEN 2
            WHEN 'Secretary' THEN 3
            WHEN 'Treasurer' THEN 4
            WHEN 'Auditor' THEN 5
            ELSE 6  -- Here replace 6 with 0
          END
```

Initially, I thought it could be due to the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag on the question, but Giorgos Betsos’s answer on the same question is formatted correctly. Is it a bug?

Comment: You need to add `<!-- language: lang-sql -->` when the first tag is a different language.

Comment: I never did that in any of my answer's upto now. Today is the first time am facing this problem

Comment: @VR46 presumably you've generally answered questions where the relevant tag for language formatting was first. If you look at the edit view of the correctly-formatted answer you can see the relevant comment (in general this is a good thing to do to see how formatting has been done).

Comment: The question doesn't seem to have any PHP anyway so I removed that tag.

Comment: @BhargavRao - Thank you :)

Comment: See also: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If none of the tags on the post have the highlighter you are looking for (in the [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) at the bottom), the posts aren't highlighted. You either need to retag the post to add the tags relevant to the question, or use the language html comment to force the code block to be interpreted one way, like this:

```sql
SELECT student.firstname, 
       candidates.partylist, 
       candidates.position 
FROM   student 
       INNER JOIN candidates 
               ON student.student_id = candidates.student_id 
ORDER  BY partylist, 
          CASE position 
            WHEN 'President' THEN 1 
            WHEN 'VicePresident' THEN 2 
            WHEN 'Secretary' THEN 3 
            WHEN 'Treasurer' THEN 4 
            WHEN 'Auditor' THEN 5 
            ELSE 6  -- Here replace 6 with 0
          END
```

Comment: Good to know :)